# Can Android toolbar menu item be made focusable?

Tags: android-toolbar

Is it possible to make the menu items of a toolbar focusable?  I am asking this because I want to use a keyboard (e.g. D-pad) to select buttons of a toolbar.  Once the overflow menu is open, the items on the overflow menu are focusable so they can be selected with a keyboard.

In this regard, Toolbar seems to be worse than Actionbar which overflow menu can be opened by the menu button of a keyboard.  The menu button does not open the overflow menu of a toolbar.

Menu items do not seem to support the focusable attribute.

The following code does not help:

```
toolbar.focusableViewAvailable(toolbar)
```

Comment: Did you find some reliable solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: These are all the menu item resources, but it lacks any focusable or background setting resource attributes.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource